# UIScrollView placement on master view of a split view controller

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am having a weird issue.  I have a split view controller and in the detail view I have a scroll view.  Inside the scroll view I have a lavel with some information.

When the application first opens in landscape, the scroll view is always placed 1/2 way down the view of the detail view.  When I touch an item in the root view and the next view shows, then I return to the scroll view, the scroll view is in the correct place (10,10).

I have set the frame of the scroll view in the viewWillAppear method of the detail view.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
        ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {

        [self setPortrait];
        CGRect tmpR = [self.view frame];
        NSLog(@"The Detail View Controller Portrait view: width: %f height: %f",tmpR.size.width, tmpR.size.height);

    } else {

        [self setLandscape];
        CGRect tmpR = [self.view frame];
        NSLog(@"The Detail View Controller Portrait view: width: %f height: %f",tmpR.size.width, tmpR.size.height);

    }

    // show the front page message....
    [self setMessage:kDetailViewMessage];

    // make sure the scroll is at the top....
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}


-(void)setLandscape {

    // set the proper scroll view size...
    CGRect navigationBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect detailWindowFrame = splitView.detailViewController.view.frame;

    CGRect sframe = CGRectZero;
    sframe.origin = CGPointMake(10, 10 + navigationBarFrame.size.height);
    sframe.size = CGSizeMake(detailWindowFrame.size.width - 20, detailWindowFrame.size.height - 20);

    [self.scrollView setFrame:sframe];

    [detailDescriptionLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sframe.size.width, sframe.size.height)];

    [detailDescriptionLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

Right now the application will only display in landscape and the setPortrait function is not called.

This has been driving me crazy for a few hours now..... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the bounds origin of the content view, not the frame. (That's how it works for NSScrollView, anyway.)